# Only 1 SubView added in 4 cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

Codes are as below

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

let fruitsComponents: [String] = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grape", "Pear"]

let fruitsTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 7.5, width: 50, height: 30))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fruitsCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = fruitsComponents[indexPath.row]
    fruitsTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    fruitsTextField.delegate = self

    cell.addSubview(fruitsTextField)

    return cell
}
```

1 section ok.

4 rows ok.

Titles for cells are Apple, Banana, Grape, Pear ok.

But only 1 subview is added to 'Pear', the 4th row.

**Question1. Why aren't 3 subviews added to the rows?**

**Question2. How can I add subviews for all of the rows?**

Thanks

Comment: There are two "big" issues: One a view (which is one of the parent class of `UITextField`) can only have one superview. So since you have only one textfield, it will be remove from the previous one. Second issue: Cells are reused, don't call `addSubview()` in `tableView(_ :cellForRowAt:)`.

Comment: Not related to your questions, but if you're using a custom `UITableViewCell` you need to cast it as the type of the cell (... `as! FruitsCell`)

Comment: Why do I need to cast it as the type of the cell? Can you explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have one instance of fruitsTextField, it can only be the subview of one row. So,

- when you add it to row 2, it will be removed from the first row
- when you add it to row 3, it will be removed from the second row

and so on.

The main problem is, that you should not add subviews each and every `cellForRow` call, because the cells are being reused, so even if you have a distinct text view for each cell, you might end up with more than one text view in each and every cell.

It is way better to create your own custom `UITableViewCell` subclass which holds a text view as a subview, connect outlets and go on with it. You can find several examples in the web, just check for "UITableViewCell subclass"